Alalonia UI привязка данных к xaml
Пытаюсь из бд вывести всех пользователей
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="Messenger.MainWindow"
        Width="800" Height="600" Title="Messenger">
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="200,*,Auto" RowDefinitions="*">
        <!-- Список пользователей -->
        <ListBox Name="UserList" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="UserSelected">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <!-- Сообщения -->
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="MessagesPanel" />
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- Ввод сообщения -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBox x:Name="MessageInput" Width="600" Height="30" />
            <Button x:Name="SendButton" Content="Send" Click="SendMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Messenger.Data;
using MsBox.Avalonia;

namespace Messenger
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        private User SelectedUser { get; set; }
        private int CurrentUserId { get; set; }

        public MainWindow(string username)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Установка текущего пользователя
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var currentUser = context.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.username == username);
                if (currentUser == null)
                {
                    throw new System.Exception("Пользователь не найден.");
                }
                CurrentUserId = currentUser.id;
                
                // Загрузка списка других пользователей
                var users = context.users.Where(u => u.id != CurrentUserId).ToList();
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    Users.Add(user);
                }
            }

            // Инициализация компонентов UI
            UserList.ItemsSource = Users; 
            UserList.SelectionChanged += UserSelected;

            // Инициализация остальных компонентов UI
            MessagesPanel = MessagesPanel ?? new StackPanel(); // Прямой доступ к MessagesPanel
             // Прямой доступ к MessageInput
            SendButton.Click += SendMessage; // Прямой доступ к SendButton
            

        }

        private void UserSelected(object? sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedUser = (User)((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
            if (SelectedUser != null)
            {
                LoadMessages();
            }
        }

        private void LoadMessages()
        {
            MessagesPanel.Children.Clear();
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var messages = context.messages
                    .Where(m => (m.senderid == CurrentUserId && m.receiverid == SelectedUser.id) ||
                (m.senderid == SelectedUser.id && m.receiverid == CurrentUserId))
                .AsEnumerable()  // Принудительно выполняем запрос на клиенте
                .OrderBy(m => m.timestamp)  // Сортировка уже на клиенте
                .ToList();
                    

                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    AddMessageToChat(message.content, message.senderid == CurrentUserId);
                }
            }
        }

        private void SendMessage(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectedUser == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MessageInput.Text))
                return;

            string messageContent = MessageInput.Text;  // Получаем текст сообщения
            AddMessageToChat(messageContent, true);
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var message = new Message
                {
                    senderid = CurrentUserId,
                    receiverid = SelectedUser.id,
                    content = messageContent  // Убедитесь, что content не пустое
                };

                // Проверяем, что content действительно не пустое
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.content))
                {
                    ShowMessage("Ошибка", "Сообщение не может быть пустым.");
                    return;
                }

                // Здесь может возникать ошибка, если content = NULL
                
                context.messages.Add(message);

                context.SaveChanges();
              
                  
            }

            
            MessageInput.Text = string.Empty;
        }


        private void AddMessageToChat(string message, bool isCurrentUser)
        {
            var textBlock = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = message,
                Margin = new Avalonia.Thickness(5),
                Background = new Avalonia.Media.SolidColorBrush(
                    isCurrentUser ? Avalonia.Media.Colors.LightBlue : Avalonia.Media.Colors.LightGray
                ),
                HorizontalAlignment = isCurrentUser ? Avalonia.Layout.HorizontalAlignment.Right : Avalonia.Layout.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                MaxWidth = 250,
                TextWrapping = Avalonia.Media.TextWrapping.Wrap
            };

            MessagesPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
        }



        private async void ShowMessage(string title, string message)
        {
            var messageBox = MessageBoxManager
            .GetMessageBoxStandard(title, message);
            var result = await messageBox.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}


public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; } // Идентификатор (PK)
    public string username { get; set; } = string.Empty; // Имя пользователя
    public string email { get; set; } = string.Empty; // Электронная почта
    public string passwordhash { get; set; } = string.Empty; // Пароль
}

но вылетает ошибка
Unable to resolve property or method of name 'username' on type 'XamlX.TypeSystem.XamlPseudoType'., строка 10, позиция 17.
не могу понят в чем проблема
может логики как то криво криво реализовал и так нельзя делать?

"{Binding username}" есть, но нет привязки коллекции, из которой брался бы объект с таким полем.

UserList.ItemsSource = Users в ItemSource передаю так

В коде в вопросе этого нет...

Нужно <ListBox Name="UserList" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="UserSelected" ItemSource="Users">. Таким образом ты привяжешься к своей обозреваемому листу, и потом из дата контекста будешь тянуть данные (из своей модели User)

<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="Messenger.MainWindow"
        Width="800" Height="600" Title="Messenger"
        xmlns:data="clr-namespace:Messenger.Data">
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="200,*,Auto" RowDefinitions="*">
        <!-- Привязка ItemsSource через привязку к Users -->
        <ListBox x:Name="UserList" Grid.Column="0" SelectionChanged="UserSelected" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:User">
                    <!-- Привязка конкретного свойства username -->
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <!-- Сообщения -->
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="MessagesPanel" />
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- Ввод сообщения -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <TextBox x:Name="MessageInput" Width="600" Height="30" />
            <Button x:Name="SendButton" Content="Send" Click="SendMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>

указал путь на класс User, и заработало.
кому интересно - полный код:
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.Interactivity;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Messenger.Data;
using MsBox.Avalonia;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Messenger
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        private User SelectedUser { get; set; }
        private int CurrentUserId { get; set; }
        public MainWindow(string username)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Установка текущего пользователя
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var currentUser = context.users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.username == username);
                if (currentUser == null)
                {
                    throw new System.Exception("Пользователь не найден.");
                }
                CurrentUserId = currentUser.id;

                // Загрузка списка других пользователей
                var users = context.users.Where(u => u.id != CurrentUserId).ToList();
                foreach (var user in users)
                {
                    Users.Add(user);
                }
            }

            // Устанавливаем ItemsSource для UserList
            DataContext = this; // Прямое связывание коллекции с ListBox

            UserList.ItemsSource = Users;

            // Инициализация компонентов UI
            UserList.SelectionChanged += UserSelected;
            MessagesPanel = MessagesPanel ?? new StackPanel();
            SendButton.Click += SendMessage;
        }




        private void UserSelected(object? sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedUser = (User)((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem;
            if (SelectedUser != null)
            {
                LoadMessages();
            }
        }

        private void LoadMessages()
        {
            MessagesPanel.Children.Clear();
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var messages = context.messages
                    .Where(m => (m.senderid == CurrentUserId && m.receiverid == SelectedUser.id) ||
                (m.senderid == SelectedUser.id && m.receiverid == CurrentUserId))
                .AsEnumerable()  // Принудительно выполняем запрос на клиенте
                .OrderBy(m => m.timestamp)  // Сортировка уже на клиенте
                .ToList();
                    

                foreach (var message in messages)
                {
                    AddMessageToChat(message.content, message.senderid == CurrentUserId);
                }
            }
        }

        private void SendMessage(object? sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (SelectedUser == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MessageInput.Text))
                return;

            string messageContent = MessageInput.Text;  // Получаем текст сообщения
            AddMessageToChat(messageContent, true);
            using (var context = new AppDbContext())
            {
                var message = new Message
                {
                    senderid = CurrentUserId,
                    receiverid = SelectedUser.id,
                    content = messageContent  // Убедитесь, что content не пустое
                };

                // Проверяем, что content действительно не пустое
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.content))
                {
                    ShowMessage("Ошибка", "Сообщение не может быть пустым.");
                    return;
                }

                // Здесь может возникать ошибка, если content = NULL
                
                context.messages.Add(message);

                context.SaveChanges();
              
                  
            }

            
            MessageInput.Text = string.Empty;
        }


        private void AddMessageToChat(string message, bool isCurrentUser)
        {
            var textBlock = new TextBlock
            {
                Text = message,
                Margin = new Avalonia.Thickness(5),
                Background = new Avalonia.Media.SolidColorBrush(
                    isCurrentUser ? Avalonia.Media.Colors.LightBlue : Avalonia.Media.Colors.LightGray
                ),
                HorizontalAlignment = isCurrentUser ? Avalonia.Layout.HorizontalAlignment.Right : Avalonia.Layout.HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                MaxWidth = 250,
                TextWrapping = Avalonia.Media.TextWrapping.Wrap
            };

            MessagesPanel.Children.Add(textBlock);
        }



        private async void ShowMessage(string title, string message)
        {
            var messageBox = MessageBoxManager
            .GetMessageBoxStandard(title, message);
            var result = await messageBox.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}

